# does throwing an error inside a do block leads to the catch block?

Tags: swift, error-handling, throw

I have a do catch block with a function inside that can throw. In the catch block I throw a specific error. I'm interested in what happens when the function throws so I threw an error instead of the function call. I expected this error to be thrown outside the function as it can throw but it seems like throwing errors inside a do block calls the catch block which I think makes sense. Could you confirm this behavior ?

Here is the code :

```
func download() throws {
    do {
        // try throwingFunc()
        throw Constants.Errors.API.invalidResponse(statusCode: 2)
    } catch {
        print("unexpected")
        throw Constants.Errors.API.invalidData
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you confirmed it yourself already.

Comment: Any thrown error in a `do` scope is being `caught`. A better practice is to remove the entire `do - catch` block and handle the error on the caller side.

Comment: @vadian The usual reasons I'd usually throw in a `catch` block in these case it's because I'd need the "lower method" to print something (or notify, send, etc for itself the error) and/or because I want to put the error inside another error (ie, usually enum error with associated value).

Comment: @Larme I agree if a *meaningful* action takes place in the `catch` scope.

Comment: @vadian Indeed, but while your previous comment is true is this current sample (and short code), I preferred to open it for clarifications in case someone thinks it's always a bad idea to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as vadian confirmed a thrown error in a do scope is being caught.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).